# Opening VS2015 Community when both Community & Professional are installed?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have both VS2015 Community and VS2015 Professional installed. How do I start VS2015 Community? I can't seem to find a link that opens it.

Comment: Why do you have two versions of Visual Studio 2015 installed on your system?

Comment: @Ramhound My Add/Remove control panel lists both editions of VS2015.

Comment: Do you want both editions installed?  My experience is that Visual Studio has no problem with having "Visual Studio 2015" and "Visual Studio 2013" but it isn't exactly designed to have two different versions of the same version of Visual Studio installed on the same system.

Comment: Are they installed on different locations on your hard drive?  If not, you'll probably only have the one you installed most recently.